# DistributionNotFound Automat

Tags: python

I am trying to install obfsproxy on google cloud compute engine.I am getting the following when I launch the following command

```
obfsproxy --log-file=obfsproxy.log --log-min-severity=info obfs4 \ 
    --dest=127.0.0.1:443 server 0.0.0.0:21194
```

[image]

I tried to following to fix it but it didn't work and the error is still the same

```
pip install Automat --upgrade
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Python 2.6 is pretty old. You might want to try upgrading to 2.7, or using an Anaconda distribution if you aren't already.

Comment: I already install Python 3.6 as an alternate install , the issue now is how to make obfsproxy use new version of python

Comment: I'd suggest installing Anaconda. It will automatically update your path/pythonpath, which is what you need to do in order to point to Python 3.6 as well